# Как задать ширину индикатора у TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tab

В общем, есть у меня ViewPager с TabLayout. У текущей вкладки есть подчеркивание - индикатор. У него можно менять цвет и высоту, но я хочу, чтобы это подчеркивание было не на всю ширину таба. Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
app:tabMinWidth=""
app:tabMaxWidth=""
```